# D3- how to select circles in a group element and set display to none

Tags: javascript, d3.js, selection, selector

I have a function to draw circles (canvasCPI and canvasGDP are my svgs):

```
    var CPIforecircles = canvasCPI.append("g");
    var GDPforecircles = canvasGDP.append("g");

    function drawGDPForecastCircles(theNum){
        GDPforecircles.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3)
        .attr("class", "circleGDPFore")
        .style("display", null)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + xScaleQuarterly(dataForecast[theNum].date) + "," + yScaleGDP(dataForecast[theNum].GDPforecast) + ")");        
    }

    function drawCPIForecastCircles(theNum){
        CPIforecircles.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 3)
        .attr("class", "circleCPIFore")
        .style("display", null)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + xScaleQuarterly(dataForecast[theNum].date) + "," + yScaleCPI(dataForecast[theNum].CPIforecast) + ")");
    }
```

then through my script call this function to draw more and more circles:

```
function generateCirclesFore(indexNum){

        for (var i=indexNum; i<counterFore+1; i++){
            drawGDPForecastCircles(i);
            drawCPIForecastCircles(i);
        }
    }
```

eventually i have two group elements (CPIforecircles and GDPforecircles) with lots of circles inside the  tags  but how to I select these circles as an array and then apply a style of display to none (.style("display", "none")) to only certain circles in that array?

Comment: `d3.selectAll(".circleCPIFore").filter(function(d) { d.someProp == someCriteria;}).style("display","none");`?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to put my comment as an answer so this is not left officially without an answer. Also, I believe the answer is accurate. So, here it is:

```
selectAll(".circleCPIFore")
    .filter(function(d) { d.someProp == someCriteria;})
    .style("display","none");
```